# Методы оптимизации больших БД для увеличения скорости выборки

Tags: mysql

После увеличения посещаемости сайта и стремительного роста БД, некоторые выборки начали занимать много времени. Особенно запросы на подсчеты статистики. Такими темпами объем таблиц будет только расти. Какие методы применяют для более быстрой выборки?

Уже посматриваю в сторону кеширования. Но там стоит проблема актуальности данных и фреймворк предлагает хранить результаты выборок в виде файлов на сервере.
Со структурой запросов и индексами тоже всё нормально, по-другому не составить.

Прошу совета.

Comment: Файлы на сервере - совсем плохо. Кешировать результаты выборок надо в Redis.

Comment: Если данные часто обновляются то кеширование не лучший вариант (он ведь не обновляется с изменениями.. и, так же, слишком большой объем кешированных данных, так же, замедляет работу). Для ускорения работы стоит использовать индексирование и связи обязательно через `foreign key`(важно таблицы в одной кодировке создавать), оптимизируйте память файлов `OPTIMIZE TABLE table1,table2,...`

Comment: @KAGGDesign с чего это?

Comment: Отдавать статичные версии страниц - нормальное решение. Но лучше оставить всё динамикой, а в in memory базу кешировать сами выборки и читать их оттуда потом перед отдачей клиенту.